# create a user on mysql database through java gui

Tags: java, mysql, swing, addition

I am coding an interface which manages a database with all DML and some DDL features. One feature should be, that an admin can add users to the database with specified priviledges. 
I know how to grant priviledges in sql i only need it done via a java application.

So is there a way to get this done safely? It probably will work with a simple executeUpdate

```
String cu = "create user"+userName+" identified by "+pw+";";
Statement stmt; 
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

but this opens my ass for injections. Is there a way to get this done safely by a preexisting method ? 
Please help me out, mighty stackoverflow community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way of doing this. Use [PrepredStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)  instead of Statement.

Comment: thanks i didnt notice the possibilities of using preparedstatement. i didnt think of putting the wildcards anywhere, sorry for not thinking of consulting the oradocs myself, should have come to my mind :S

Answer (score 1):

You need gap and  quation `'` for password,

```
 String cu = "create user "+userName+" identified by '"+pw+"';";
                         |
                         |_put gap here
```

Comment: this was just a quick sample of my thoughts i know the syntax, but thanks